# request.is_secure() returning False behind double proxy

Tags: django, apache, nginx, proxy

How do I make `request.is_secure()` show true when behind a double proxy?

Currently, there is an https only nginx that is public and it proxies to an http only apache instance that is actually hosting the Django app. Do I need to change something in our configs?

#### Nginx

```
location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 6000;
    proxy_read_timeout 6000;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

#### Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerName example.com

    ### Logs ###
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" common
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    ### Site specific WSGI file ###
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    KeepAlive Off
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=1 threads=20 inactivity-timeout=20
    WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/usr/src/current/conf/apache/script.wsgi.py"
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory "/">
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header)

If I read your config well, I think this should work:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_SCHEME', 'https')
```

Comment: Ah, it was `HTTP_X_SCHEME`, found it by dumping `request.META`